# Do I have to use App Engine to write glassware with Mirror API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-mirror-api

I am trying Python quickstart project (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/python) and it is implemented on GAE, however, looking at the code it does not seem that there is much dependency on App Engine itself (code is kind of complicated and I still do not understand it all though).

Is this required to host Mirror-based glassware on App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this required to host Mirror-based glassware on App Engine?

No, it is not required. What you really need is ability to use [Google API's](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) and Mirror API is just one of them.

[Java quick start](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/java), for example does not run on top of GAE.